# Pandas Timedelta to add decimal hours to existing timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

**Aim:**
I would like to use Timedelta to add hours, in decimal format, to an existing timestamp. My current code is giving me an issue - probably because I don't know how to not create a list (been struggling for a while on how to address things). Heh.

I have a dataframe named 'df' that looks roughly like the following:

```
+---------------------+----------+
|        Time         | AddHours |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2019-11-13 09:30:00 | 3.177481 |
| 2019-11-13 09:30:00 | 2.752435 |
| 2019-11-13 09:30:00 | 3.129910 |
| 2019-11-13 09:30:00 | 3.078170 |
| 2019-11-13 09:30:00 | 2.105979 |
| 2019-11-13 09:30:00 | 3.086892 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

**Field Data Types**
Because it's probably useful to know the datatype for this exercise:
df.dtypes returns:

```
Time          datetime64[ns]
AddHours            float64 <-- The units are hours. Eg 3.1202 hours
```

**Existing / Problem Code**
Now - the part I'm having trouble with.
I currently have:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'] + [pd.Timedelta(hours=ts) for ts in df['AddHours']]
```

This returns an error that I don't know how to overcome. I assume that "for ts in df['AddHours']" is returning a list, where really I just want to add df['Time'] + df['AddHours'] for each row in the dataframe, and that Timedelta allows me to treat AddHours as decimal hours.

Any bright ideas on where I'm going wrong, and how to fix it?

**Error:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert to `Timedeltas`s:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['AddHours'], unit='H')
print (df)
                        Time  AddHours
0 2019-11-13 12:40:38.931600  3.177481
1 2019-11-13 12:15:08.766000  2.752435
2 2019-11-13 12:37:47.676000  3.129910
3 2019-11-13 12:34:41.412000  3.078170
4 2019-11-13 11:36:21.524400  2.105979
5 2019-11-13 12:35:12.811200  3.086892
```

Your solution is possible by convert list to `Index`, but I think slow if large `DataFrame`:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'] + pd.Index([pd.Timedelta(hours=ts) for ts in df['AddHours']])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first solution worked perfectly. Please also keep the second one for reference, it also looks pretty useful.