# adding time to existing pandas date field

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

my dataframe stores time like this:

```
_df['date']
"2020-06-12 01:36:00.000"
```

I want to append 8 hours to the time so I tried doing this:

```
_df['date'] = _df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(8, unit='H')
```

With the goal of having  `"2020-06-12 09:36:00.000"` as the final time

This is the error I get :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta' and 'str'
```

I'm guessing i need to first convert this to a date time object in python then do a time delta on top of that? I thought pandas could support this based off of this post: [Pandas Timedelta to add decimal hours to existing timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006263/pandas-timedelta-to-add-decimal-hours-to-existing-timestamp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes before add timedelta, because column `date` has string repr of datetetimes:

```
print (_df['date'].dtype)

_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(_df['date']) + pd.to_timedelta(8, unit='H')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `_df['date']` is a `str` while the `pd.to_timedelta(8, unit='H')` is a `Timedelta`. You have to convert the `_df['date']` to `Timedelta` first using `pd.to_datetime(_df['date'])` and then add them together.